# iOS SDK : WebRTC integration to my iOS application

Tags: ios, webrtc

I want to integrate WebRTC to my project. I have downloaded its sdk from following URL :
https://github.com/gandg/webrtc-ios

I Want to know how exactly i can integrate this to my project to make voice call and video call available for me.

Answer (score 0):

What you've downloaded is not SDK, but this is an example project that demonstrates audio/video calls on iOS devices. It uses precompiled WebRTC binaries and has XCode project file, that can be opened and compiled in the IDE easily. If you're an iOS developer, you can just take this application and modify it building your own.